# Strange behaviour when connect to database in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm connecting to Mysql Database With following code. I'm  using `mysqli`. But It's not connecting to mysql database.

```
define("HOST", "hostname");
define("USER", "username");
define("PASS", "password");
define("DB", "dbname");

$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS) or die("Couldn't make database connection.");
$db = mysqli_select_db($link, DB) or die("Couldn't select database");
```

Strange things is that when I delete `or die("Couldn't make database connection.")` and `or die("Couldn't select database");` then it's connect to db. Why ? Is there anything I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: no, you're not connected to the db. you're just removing the code that TELLS YOU you're not connected. Instead of outputting a fixed/useless error message, output the ACTUAL error message: `or die(mysqli_error())`

Comment: Ok I'm doing this. Let's see what happen.

Comment: Now it's showing blank page after I add `die(mysqli_error())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [proposed way to handle the situation](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.construct.php):

```
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```